# can't realise if inside while loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

help me please. i can't realise IF inside WHILE:

```
    while IFS=';' read one two three; 
do

if (( $three >= 1 )) #this is a line that i can't understand

then X=$(for i in $two
   do BIN=$(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; $i" | bc )
   echo $BIN
   done)
fi
done < /testcsv.csv
```

and output is:

```
./test.sh: line 34: ((: <= 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= 1 ")
```

Comment: And exactly which part of what you've written is line 34?

Comment: Are you sure you give enough info to read? when prompted, you should enter three terms separated by semicolons, the last one should be a number (and very likely that's what you missed to obtain the error you obtained), the second one should be a list of hex numbers separated by spaces. But honestly, it's a horrible piece of code, and it's subject to code injection. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an IF in bash would be something of the following:

```
if [ conditional expression ]
```

In your case:

```
if [ $three >= 1 ]
```

Comment: It is? I just did a short test (OS X Bash 3.2.53) with his syntax and got that _(error token is ..)_ thing. Solved by the brackets in my example.

Comment: @mattias In test, `>=` does a lexical sorting test. By contrast, in modern bash anyway, `(( $three >= 1 ))` does a numerical comparison. If `((...))` is not available on OSX, then the OP probably wants `[ "$three" -ge 1 ]`.